# Double integral using jacobian

Tags: jacobian

I have to evaluate following integral
$\int_0^\infty\int_{-y}^yf(x,y)dxdy$
using $u=x^2-y^2, v=x^2+y^2$.
Actual form of function f is not important here, except for that it's odd function of y.
So the area in uv plane is 
$\int_0^\infty\int_{-\infty}^0f(u,v)/\lvert J(u,v/x,y)\rvert dudv$
  But I feel like that the above integral is somewhat incomplete, cuz it includes also y<0 case.
However the answer is just the value of above integral.
Can someone explain what's wrong in my logic?

Comment: Can you show how you know the answer is just the value of that integral, without $1/2$?

Comment: OK. The function is $f(x,y)=y*\lvert x \rvert exp(-2(x^4+y^4))$.   Wolfram alpha says that the value is $\pi/32$, and the value of integral above is the same.

Comment: @MathLover can you explain more? I can't see your point. Integral with your range results in $3\pi/64$

Answer (score 1):

The reparametrization isn't injective, so you have to split the domain into 2 pieces such that the restriction to each piece is injective. What you need to consider seperately is $x>0$ and $x<0$, so it's actually the fact that $f$ is a even function of $x$ that allows to consider just one case, and multiply the result by $2$.

If $x>0$ then
$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad u=x^2-y^2\ ,\ v=x^2+y^2$ and $0<y\ ,-y<x<y$
can be rewritten to
$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad (x,y) = \left(\sqrt{\frac{u+v}{2}},\sqrt{\frac{v-u}{2}}\right)$ with $u<0$ and $-u<v$.
Hence 
$$\int_0^\infty\int_{-y}^yf(x,y)dxdy = 2\int_ {-\infty}^0 \int_ {-u}^\infty f\left(\sqrt{\frac{u+v}{2}},\sqrt{\frac{v-u}{2}}\right)\frac{1/4}{\sqrt{(v-u) (u+v)}}dv\ du$$
where $\frac{1/4}{\sqrt{(v-u) (u+v)}}$ is the absolute determinant of the Jacobian of $\left(\sqrt{\frac{u+v}{2}},\sqrt{\frac{v-u}{2}}\right)$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But what the -u < v inequality means? If I substitute x and y I just got x^2>0.

Comment: @Septacle For the case $x>0$ we have $x>0\Rightarrow x^2>0\Rightarrow (u+v)/2>0 \Rightarrow u+v>0\Rightarrow -u<v$

Comment: O Thank you. I got it. But the problem (for me, not ur answer) is that my function is not integrable for that range. (in elementary func.). f (u,v)=e^-(u^2+v^2)